# Can I reopen a closed channel?

Tags: go, channel

I am trying to figure out whether I can reopen a channel after closing it.

Test case:

1. I have a channel with some things in it
2. I want to range over them therefore I need to close the channel beforehand
3. I want to put more stuff in the channel and iterate through it once more

```
go func() {
    queue <- "1"
    queue <- "2"
    close(queue)
}()

for i := range queue {
    go func(i string) {
        fmt.Println("From queue: ", i)
    }(i)
}

go func() {
    open(queue)
    queue <- "3"
    queue <- "4"
    close(queue)
}()

for i := range queue {
    go func(i string) {
        fmt.Println("From queue: ", i)
    }(i)
}
```

- Of course `open` does not exist. How can I implement something like what I need in Go?
- I don't want to use the Sleep function

Comment: No, there is no way to reopen a channel besides creating a new one in its place.

Comment: " I want to range over them therefore I need to close the channel beforehand" --> no you don't need  to close the channel. your loop will run whenever there is an item in the channel. it will only *exit* when the channel is closed.

Comment: Does https://play.golang.org/p/g2xBoM4M7up do what you need?

Comment: Either don't close the channel or recreate it after closing (`make(chan string)`)

Answer (score 6):

> I want to range over them **therefore I need to close the channel** beforehand

**Nope, no need to close the channel**. It'll resume iteration when another item is pushed thru the channel.

The below code accepts console input and pushes it to the channel:

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "fmt"
)

func process(c chan string) {
    for s := range c {
        log.Println("processed", s)
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan string, 10)
    go process(c)

    // get from console and process
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println("INPUT STUFF. TYPE #quit TO EXIT.")
    for {
        input, _, _ := reader.ReadLine()
        if string(input) == "#quit" {
            break
        }
        c <- string(input)
    }

    log.Println("BYE!")
}
```

**output**

```
INPUT STUFF. TYPE #quit TO EXIT.
hello
2018/10/23 10:43:52 processed hello
world
2018/10/23 10:43:54 processed world
#quit
2018/10/23 10:43:57 BYE!
```

The below sample uses `Sleep()` and is runnable as a Go Playground [snippet](https://play.golang.org/p/laOF5aWyY-5)

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

func process(c chan string) {
    for s := range c {
        log.Println("processed", s)
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan string, 10)

    go process(c)

    // push some data
    c <- "barry allen"
    c <- "iris west"

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)

    // push more data
    c <- "joe west"
    c <- "caitlin snow"

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
}
```

**output**

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 processed barry allen
2009/11/10 23:00:00 processed iris west
2009/11/10 23:00:02 processed joe west
2009/11/10 23:00:02 processed caitlin snow
```

Hope this helps. Cheers,

Comment: That'll do but I don't want to use the Sleep function, I find it hacky. Sorry, forgot to add it to the question.

Comment: @Jack, you don't _need_ to use `Sleep` it's just used to illustrate what's going on (same in my answer).

Comment: Ok, you may try the above edit. Uses command-line input instead to show that `process` function works over time.

Comment: Edited answer so both samples are present (I'm a fan of having runnable sample in Go Playground) :)

Comment: Okay I see. Thank you Jonathan. 
How would you change the code to not use an infinite loop to prevent the termination of the program? I guess a waitgroup could do?

Comment: For a command line input pgm, I'd recognize special keywords that the user can type in to terminate the flow. I've updated the 1st example in the answer to reflect this. Notice the addition of lines with `if` and `break` keywords.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reopen a closed channel but you *can* send a `channel` on a channel, perhaps [this is what you're looking for](https://play.golang.org/p/a6d9rX0UJnN)?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    queue := make(chan chan int)
    defer close(queue)

    go func() { // reader
        for {
            ch := <-queue
            for i := range ch {
                fmt.Println(i)
            }
            fmt.Println("Done with this channel")
        }
    }()

    go func() { // writer-1
        ch := make(chan int)
        defer close(ch)
        queue <- ch
        ch <- 4
        ch <- 2
    }()

    go func() { // writer-2
        ch := make(chan int)
        defer close(ch)
        queue <- ch
        ch <- 4
        ch <- 20
    }()
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

Comment: One thing I would suggest is to use wait groups instead of `time.Sleep()`

Comment: @xReprisal, true but this is just an example, when I tried to use wait groups I got [something more cumbersome](https://play.golang.org/p/t-z3FHAKnV9).

Answer (score 0):

Tho you cannot reopen the channel, it is possible to create a new one and assign to the variable. The previously closed channel will be garbage collected. In this case I reused the `queue` variable, but you can also create a new `queue2` variable and pass it to the goroutine.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    queue := make(chan int)
    go printFormat(nil, queue)
    queue <- 1
    queue <- 2
    close(queue)
    // fake some actions in between
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    queue = make(chan int)
    go printFormat(cancel, queue)
    queue <- 3
    queue <- 4
    close(queue)
    <-ctx.Done()
}

func printFormat(c context.CancelFunc, q chan int) {
    for i := range q {
        fmt.Printf("Data %d \n", i)
    }
    if c != nil {
        c()
    }
}
```